# Push button switch terminology question

Tags: button, terminology

What is the proper term for the upper part, the one we push on push button switches? Is it button or knob (I also saw it referred as head and actuator)? I am asking because I want to buy some for a project but I don't want the whole mechanism for the contact to be made, just the plastic upper part. Red part in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW8EC.jpg) picture.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's called a button. Button is something you push, knob is something you twist, in general.

Comment: Also known as switch actuator or plunger.

Answer (score 1):

So if I am not mistaken, you are only asking for the bit of plastic that you push and nothing else, none of the contacts or anything?

If that is the case, I've done some digging and I have found that they are called 'caps', push button caps to be more precise, found a whole load on RS: [Take a look here](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/switches/push-button-switches-accessories/push-button-caps/?searchTerm=push%20button).
But I am sure that there are plenty of other options if you look around, I typed in 'tactile switch accessories' to come up with this among many other things before I actually found what I think you are looking for!

Would probably be easier just to buy the push button, actuator, tactile switch, whatever you want to call it, rather than make one but each to there own! Hope this helps.